# Compare and Convert double to Integers and omit unwanted charecters

Tags: java

Please I am new in Java so I have a problem with my code here which I wanted to input any number from the Scanner on only one Line and check if the type is Integer, than it will proceed to compute some operations but if it's a double, it has to convert it to integer only, and if a character is entered otherwise, it should omit it. Anyways my code is there below which I completely am lost with in it because it can't run as per expecting it  too. Help me notify where I went wrong. Thanks.

> MY codes below

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Converter {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your numbers: ");
    String data = scan.nextLine();

    String space[] = data.split(" "); //Space

    int n[] = new int [space.length];    
    int count = 0, sum = 0;
    Integer a;
    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++){

        n[i] = Integer.parseInt(space[i]);
        a = n[i];
        if (a instanceof Integer){
            count +=1;
            sum+= n[i];
        }
        else{
            Double c;
            for (int j = 0; j < n.length; j++){
                n[j] = (int) Double.parseDouble(space[i]);
                 c = (double) n[j];
                if (c instanceof Double){
                    int x = c.intValue();
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.deleteCharAt(n[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    double av = sum/n.length;
    System.out.println("\nSum is " +sum+"\n"+"Average is "+av);

}
```

}

Comment: please post your code here as text

Comment: *it can't run as per expecting it to*. What **specifically** is the problem?

Comment: Ok, thanks my code is shown above

Comment: I wanted it to only accept integers and ignore any charecters apart from integers, if a double is entered it should change it to type int.

Comment: Btw `a instanceof Integer` and `c instanceof Double` are completely redundant because those are the *declared types* of those variables.

Comment: So what's wrong with `(int)Double.parseDouble(...)`?

Comment: I tried to declare them that way so I can use other methods but am completely lost

Comment: to check if it's a double so I can change it to int

Comment: if (c instanceof Double){
                    int x = c.intValue();

Comment: The above is to change it to int and later proceed with the operations, but now I'm lost as nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

The return value from `Integer.parseInt()` is a *primitive* `int`. When you then assign it to the `Integer` variable `a`, it is auto-boxed to an `Integer` object. You then check `a instanceof Integer`.

There are two problems with that:

- Since `a` is declared to be an `Integer`, it is *guaranteed* to be an `Integer`, so `a instanceof Integer` will *always* be true. It's a meaningless test.
- [`Integer.parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) will *"throw a `NumberFormatException` if the string does not contain a parsable integer"* (quoted from javadoc).

So, your code will not work.

One way to do what you want, is to `try` parsing the value as an integer, then `catch` the exception if it is not a "parsable" integer. Then do the same for `double`.

```
try {
    n[i] = Integer.parseInt(space[i]);
    count++;   // same as count += 1, but better
    sum += n[i];
} catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
    try {
        n[i] = (int) Double.parseDouble(space[i]);
        count++;   // same as count += 1, but better
        sum += n[i];
    } catch (NumberFormatException e2) {
        // other logic here
    }
}
```

Don't really understand what you're trying to do when both fail, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I missed out at the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need to do is stop piling on more and more fixes every time it doesn't work. If a method doesn't work for you, revert it and try something else. I have included a simplified version of your code below which I believe addresses your issues.

Please don't just take it at face value, learn from it.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your numbers: ");
        String data = scan.nextLine();

        String space[] = data.split(" "); //Space 
        int count = 0, sum = 0;
        double a;
        int b;
        for (int i = 0; i < space.length; i++){
            try
            {
                a = Double.parseDouble(space[i]);
                b = (int)Math.round(a);
                count +=1;
                sum += b;
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
            {
                System.out.println("entry omitted as non-number: " + space[i]);
            }
        }
        int av = sum/count;
        System.out.println("\nSum is " +sum+"\n"+"Average is "+av);

    }
```

Comment: Thank youu very much!, it worked as I expected. I'll do more research on this try-catch method.

Comment: What is the point of calling `Math.round()` *after* already truncating the value by casting `double` value to a `long`? You're in effect converting `double` to `long` to `float` to `int`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I was in a bit of a rush at the time. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on exceptions use regexes.
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Converter {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your numbers: ");
    String data = scan.nextLine();

    String space[] = data.split(" "); //Space

    int n[] = new int [space.length];    
    int count = 0, sum = 0;
    Integer a;

    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++){
        Matcher doubleReg = Pattern.compile("C=\\d+.\\d+").matcher(space[i]);
        Matcher intReg = Pattern.compile("C=\\d+").matcher(space[i]);

        if (doubleReg.find()){
            n[i] = Double.parseDouble(space[i]);
            count++;

        }
        else if(intReg.find()){

            n[i] = Integer.parseInt(space[i]);
            count++;            
        }
        else
        {
           n[i] = 0;
           count+=0;
        }
        sum += n[i];
        System.out.println("Sum " + sum );
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i understood but will do more research on regexes. Thanks all for the ideas, it worked as I expected.